# How to fill data table through loop in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I have selected rows data table through loop how can i fill matching records in Data Base to another data table

my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= selectedrows.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                string date1 = selectedrows.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
                System.DateTime dateexcel = System.DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                //check select rows exists or not in DB
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UploadTable where Date='" + dateexcel+"'", con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DBdt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(DBdt); // Here i need to fill all the rows matching in DB not a one row
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: DBdt should have all the rows in it by then..... However, it will only hold all the rows from that one query, you've looped through something else, the only way to collate them would be to copy the rows from DBdt, to a overall copy and append each itteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataTable.Merge`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DataTable mainTable = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i <= selectedrows.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string date1 = selectedrows.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
    System.DateTime dateexcel = System.DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //check select rows exists or not in DB
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UploadTable where Date='" + dateexcel+"'", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var dBdt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dBdt); 
    mainTable.Merge(dBdt);
}
```

Comment: Hi @tim-schmelter, It's working but how can i insert `selectedrows` datatable rows into `DataBase`. Can you please tell me. Thank you

Comment: @Ben805: in this question you want to select records from the database. Ask a new question where you ask how to insert records into the database.